# move old data to new database with seed in entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity, code-first

i want move my stored data from database to new changed database so i used seed but this is not work and No information is transmitted to the new database.

```
 public class AzmonContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BookGroup> Group { get; set; }
    public AzmonContext()
       : base("default")
    { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new MyDbContextInitializer(modelBuilder);

        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
public class MyDbContextInitializer : 
SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<AzmonContext>
    {
        public MyDbContextInitializer(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            : base(modelBuilder) { }
protected override void Seed(AzmonContext context)
            {
                using (var db = new AzmonContext())
                {
                    var data = db.Users.ToList();
                    var data2 = db.Group.ToList();
                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        context.Users.Add(new User
                        {
                            Name = item.Name,
                            LName = item.LName,
                            Class = item.Class
                        });
                    }

                    foreach (var item in data2)
                    {
                        context.Group.Add(new BookGroup
                        {
                            GroupName = item.GroupName,
                        });
                    }
                }

                base.Seed(context);
            }
}
}
```

so how i can do this? is there something wrong?

Comment: using (var db = new AzmonContext()), is old DbContext same as new DbContext?

Comment: yes is same....

Comment: so?, the old data is on the new database? i dont understand, you have 2 databases or one?

Comment: i have one database, when model changed my database drop and Create again and seed runs, so i want when model changed and database droped i move data to recreated database